# Obeylines in letterhead

Tags: line-breaking, koma-script, letters

when I am writing a letter and using the class `scrlttr2`. I would like to use `\obeylines` for the address, so I can just paste an address into my latex source code, i.e. somewhat like this:

```
\begin{letter}{\obeylines
Peter Paul Porkins
Ponderosa Ranch 
Philadelphia
}}
```

However, this does not work at all, there are no linebreaks in the compiled document. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The argument to `\begin{letter}` needs a ``\\`` to delimit the recipient name, at least in the standard `letter` class. Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: After examining the code of `scrlttr2.cls`, I saw that the same is made here, so the ``\\`` is necessary for the macros to work. Delimiting arguments with end-of-lines is not really recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `scrlttr2.cls` defines the `letter` environment in the following way:

```
\newenvironment{letter}[2][]{%
  \newpage
  \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else\thispagestyle{empty}\null\newpage\fi\fi
  \setcounter{page}{\@ne}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \interlinepenalty=200\@processto{#2}%
  \KOMAoptions{#1}%
  \@beginletterhook
}{%
  \stopletter\@@par\pagebreak\@@par%
}
\newcommand*{\stopletter}{}
\newcommand{\@processto}[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
    \expandafter\@xproc#1\\\@nil\ifkomavarempty{toaddress}{}{%
    \expandafter\@xproc#1\@nil}%
  \fi
}
\long\def\@xproc#1\\#2\@nil{%
  \setkomavar{toname}{#1}\setkomavar{toaddress}{#2}}
```

This means that a syntax like

```
\begin{letter}{
  Peter Paul Porkins \\
  Ponderosa Ranch \\
  Philadelphia
}
```

is required (leading or trailing spaces are mostly irrelevant), because `\@xproc` *needs* a `\\` for determining what's the recipient's name to store in the `toname` variable and the recipient's address in the `toaddress` variable.

The command's definition makes it possible to use a macro instead of the full address, so

```
\newcommand{\porkins}{%
  Peter Paul Porkins \\
  Ponderosa Ranch \\
  Philadelphia}
```

in the preamble and

```
\begin{letter}{\porkins}
```

would work.

To the contrary, `\obeylines` is use for *printing* text respecting the line ends in the typescript.

Delimiting arguments with end-of-lines can be done, but is very fragile. It would be very difficult to make `\begin{letter}` into accepting both syntaxes.

Comment: Although it's bad news, it's quite conclusive. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Sorry. I'd add that relying on line endings is in general not a good thing to do, since editors may have the tendency of messing them up.